# How can I remove URLs from a text vector using the stringr package?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a piece of text: `"At https://www.google.com/ you can google questions!"` and I want to remove the URL with the package `tidytext` by using `str_remove_all`.

- How can I do it?
- If I have a vector with more text like this, how can I remove the URL for any element in the vector ?

Comment: What is your expected output? It's also worth noting that `str_remove_all` is from `stringr`. Could you also add sample data that probably covers the whole picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gsub` from base R and a regular expression. Makes your life easier.

```
text <- "At https://www.google.com/ you can google questions!"

gsub('http\\S+\\s*', '', text)

[1]  "At you can google questions!"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a somewhat more involved regex for URLs than in the other answer, in order to be more robust to different kinds of URLs.

If you are accustomed to using tidyverse tools elsewhere in your workflow, using the `str_remove_all()` function from [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/) is a great idea. This function is vectorized, so you can pass it a vector of text.

```r
example <- c("At https://www.google.com/ you can google questions!",
             "Come to https://www.stackoverflow.com/ for R answers",
             "How many repos are there at https://www.stackoverflow.com/?")

library(stringr)
url_regex <- "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"

str_remove_all(example, url_regex)
#> [1] "At  you can google questions!" "Come to  for R answers"       
#> [3] "How many repos are there at "
```

If you put your text into a dataframe, you can also use `str_remove_all()` in a straightforward manner:

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(example) %>%
    mutate(cleaned = str_remove_all(example, url_regex))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   example                                          cleaned                 
#>   <chr>                                            <chr>                   
#> 1 At https://www.google.com/ you can google quest… At  you can google ques…
#> 2 Come to https://www.stackoverflow.com/ for R an… Come to  for R answers  
#> 3 How many repos are there at https://www.stackov… "How many repos are the…
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>